# How to make psql restore of a database ignore the owner information?

Tags: postgresql, psql

My database is associated with different usernames on the server and on my local machine. Whenever I try to restore it on my local machine from the backup downloaded from the server using the command

```
psql -d dbname -f backupfile.sql
```

I get the error output saying that

```
ERROR: role "myusername" does not exist
```

Despite the error message, the actual restore goes through. But it is annoying to see multiple error messages saying the same thing (once for each table). Is there a way I can suppress this error message. I searched quite a bit but could not find anything. There is `no-owner` option for `pgrestore`, but I could not find anything for psql.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is easy. Use the `--no-owner` and `--no-privileges` options of `pg_dump`.

You might be more happy if you used the custom format of `pg_dump` (`-F c`). Then you'd restore with `pg_restore` and could specify the options at restore time.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder, restore with `.sql` file extension, not with `.dump` file.

Comment: @KiryMeas Thanks for the reminder, but it leaves me a bit clueless. The extension doesn't have a lot of meaning where I come from...

Comment: @laurnz I tried with the `.dump` file using `pg_restore` it raised an error "You can not restore with `.dump` file". I use `pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1)`

Comment: @KiryMeas That doesn't look like a PostgreSQL error message... How did you create that `.dump` file?

Comment: Yes, it is not the exact message. here is the command I use `pg_dump -U user development --no-owner --no-privileges --data-only -F c -n test > test_development_2022_11_28.dump`

Comment: @KiryMeas That should work just fine with `pg_restore`, unless you have a PostgreSQL version incompatibility or there are foreign keys in schema `test` that point to tables that don't exist at the target database.

Comment: Ok, You're right. I concurred. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing you can do with `psql`, but plenty you can do with your `backupfile.sql`. You can remove the owner clauses on the fly:

```
grep -v '^ALTER.*OWNER TO myusername;$' backupfile.sql | psql -d dbname
```

or replace one user to another:

```
sed '/^ALTER.*OWNER TO myusername;$/s/OWNER TO myusername/OWNER TO foobar/g' backupfile.sql | psql -d dbname
```

Comment: Thank you. This is good to know. I think I am going to use the solution by @Laurenz, hence will check that as the answer. But yours probably answers my question more directly. It is a dilemma.